# Sending a number over TCP/IP for example 15 but I receive 0 at the other end. Only in the executable release version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, tcp, winsock

If I run the Debug option or the release option in visual studio everything works. BUT if run the release outside of Visual Studio the TCP/IP Client sends 0 instead of 15 (or any other number). I guess I am doing something wrong when it comes to releasing, already had a question for a different problem in this project that did the same worked in debug but not in release.

I guess it has something to do with the following lines. Because it shows me a warning (Index '7' is out of valid index range '0' to '0' for possibly stack allocated buffer 'userInput_converted'.) but if I get rid of the warning it doesn’t work at all.

```
uint32_t userInput_converted[1]; //this line makes the warning go away if I declare it bigger
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(userInput); i++) {
    userInput_converted[i] = htonl(userInput[i]); //this line shows the warning
}
```

My Main.cpp

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cassert>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include "TCP-IP-Client.h"

HWND hWndEdit;
wchar_t buffer[1024];


LRESULT CALLBACK MessageHandler(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (uMsg) {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (LOWORD(wParam) == 10) {
            GetWindowText(hWndEdit, buffer, 1024);
            int Input[1024] = { _wtoi(buffer) };
            switch (TcpIpClient(Input)) {
            case 10:
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Can't start Winsock" , L"Benachrichtigung", MB_ICONERROR);
                break;
            case 11:
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Can't create socket", L"Benachrichtigung", MB_ICONERROR);
                break;
            case 12:
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Can't connect to server", L"Benachrichtigung", MB_ICONERROR);
                break;
            case 13:
                MessageBox(hWnd, L"Socket Error!", L"Benachrichtigung", MB_ICONERROR);
                break;
            }
            
        }
        break;
    case WM_CTLCOLOREDIT:
        if (hWndEdit == (HWND)lParam) {
            HDC hdc = (HDC)wParam;
            SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(211, 211, 211));
            //SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(211, 211, 211)); // For diffrent color of latters
            SetDCBrushColor(hdc, RGB(211, 211, 211));
            return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH);
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        TextOut(hdc, 20, 20, L"Gewünschte Taster Zyklen Eingeben", strlen("Gewünschte Taster Zyklen Eingeben"));
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    HWND hWnd;
    HWND hButton;
    WNDCLASS wc;
    MSG msg;

    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = MessageHandler;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WINAPITest";

    RegisterClass(&wc);

    //assert(RegisterClass(&wc));

    hWnd = CreateWindow(L"WINAPITest", L"TasterTestVorrichtung", WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 300, 200, 0, 0, hInstance, 0);
    hButton = CreateWindow(L"button", L"OK", WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD, 40, 100, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)10, hInstance, 0);
    //hButton = CreateWindow(L"button", L"Verbinden", WS_VISIBLE | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON | WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD, 40, 100, 200, 50, hWnd, (HMENU)11, hInstance, 0);
    hWndEdit = CreateWindow(L"edit", NULL, WS_TABSTOP | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE, 40, 48, 200, 50, hWnd, 0, 0, 0);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    //ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My Tcp-Ip-Client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "CSV-Writer.h"
#include <vector>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


using namespace std;

int TcpIpClient(int userInput[])
{
    string ipAddress = "192.168.0.2";           // IP Address of the server
    int port = 2000;                        // Listening port # on the server

    // Initialize WinSock
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        //cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
        return 10;
    }

    // Create socket
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        //cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 11;
    }

    // Fill in a hint structure
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    // Connect to server
    int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 12;
    }

    // Do-while loop to send and receive data
    char buf[4096];
    bool active = true;
    bool a = false;

    do
    {
        // Prompt the user for some text
        //cout << "> ";
        //cin >> userInput[0];


        if (sizeof(userInput) > 0 && a == false)        // Make sure the user has typed in something
        {
            uint32_t userInput_converted[1];
            for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(userInput); i++) {
                userInput_converted[i] = htonl(userInput[i]);
            }
            int sendResult = send(sock, (char*)userInput_converted, sizeof(userInput_converted), 0);
            if (sendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                //std::cout << "Socket Error!";
                return 13;
            }
            a = true;
        }
            // Wait for response
            ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
            int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                short int* ibuf = (short int*)buf;
                std::vector<int> InputData;
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesReceived / 2; ++i, ++ibuf)
                {
                    short result = ntohs(*ibuf);
                    InputData.push_back(result);
                    //std::cout << result << std::endl;

                }
                if(CsvWriter(InputData)==0){
                }
                active = false;
            

        }

    } while (active == true);

    // Gracefully close down everything
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

My CSV-Writer.cpp

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


bool createFile(std::string file_name);
bool checkIfFileExist(std::string file_name);
bool writeInFile(std::string file_name, std::vector<int> dataToWrite);


int CsvWriter(std::vector<int> data) {


    if (checkIfFileExist("test.csv") == false) {
        createFile("test.csv");
    }
    std::string fileName = "test.csv";
    //std::vector<int> data;
    writeInFile(fileName, data);

    return 0;
}

bool checkIfFileExist(std::string file_name) {
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open(file_name);
    if ((fs.rdstate() & std::fstream::failbit) != 0) {
        //std::cout << "Error 'test.csv' dose not exist\n";
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }

}

bool createFile(std::string file_name) {
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open(file_name, std::fstream::app);
    fs << "Gesamtschaltungen" << "," << "Schalter Nr" << "," << "Kontakt" << "," << "Fehlschaltungen" << std::endl;
    fs.close();
    //std::cout << "test.csv was created\n";
    return true;
}

bool writeInFile(std::string file_name, std::vector<int> dataToWrite) {
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open(file_name, std::fstream::app);
    int j = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < dataToWrite.size(); i++) {
        //if (i != dataToWrite.size() - 1) {
            //fs << dataToWrite[i] << ",";
            if (i == 0) {
                fs << dataToWrite[i] << ",";
            }
            else if (i==1) {
                fs << j << "," << 1<< "," << dataToWrite[i] << std::endl;
            } else if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                fs << "," << j << "," << 2 << "," << dataToWrite[i] << std::endl;
                j++;
            }
            else
            {
                fs << "," << j << "," << 1 << "," << dataToWrite[i] << std::endl;
            }
        }
        //else {
        //  fs << " " << "," << 2 << "," << dataToWrite[i] << std::endl;
        //}
    //}
    fs.close();
    return true;
}
```

My Tcp-Ip-client.h

```
#pragma once
int TcpIpClient(int userInput[]);
```

My CSV-Writer.h

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
int CsvWriter(std::vector<int> data);
```

I hope I haven’t done something brutally simple wrong and hope that someone can help me out here.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. We don't need to see your windowing code to understand the issue.

Comment: sizeof(userInput) doesn't mean what you think it means. Your code writes past the end of an array. userInput_converted is an array of 1 number but you write 4 or 8 numbers into that array

Comment: @linspectable i have tried the last three houers to produce a minimal reproducible example and i can't, what i showed you here is the minimal i am able to do and have the problem i am having.

Comment: @user253751 I know that the array is of size 1 and that I am writing outside of the array, now that I have tried for the last 3 hours to do a minimal reproducible example it now tells me that that array gets corrupted, but it works until the program wants to close. if I change the array size to 1024 the size of the original input it does something completely different to the problem I have. it now gives me something around -13450 or so if I send 10, it's not like in my starting problem that it ever doesn’t work at all or sends 0

Comment: @Hatux Do you actually know what the program is supposed to do? "Write outside the end of the array" is not something most people want their programs to do, so the fact that the program is doing that and you're okay with it suggests that you're floundering, trying totally random things until something hopefully works. So take a step back and think about what the program is supposed to do, what it's actually doing, and why those things are different.

Comment: I should remind you that when you write outside the end of the array, it can overwrite other random variables in your program. When random variables might be getting overwritten, it will be very difficult to understand why the program is doing anything! So, fix that.

Comment: @user253751 I know what it is supposed to be doing and yes I have tried totally random things to get it to work, and I ended up at a point that it works until I released it to do it’ s work on a different PC.  I totally agree with you, and I tried to fix that array for days now but it’s not working. Every source of information I come across is either outdated or not understandable for a self-taught “beginner” what I still consider me as.

Comment: Do you understand how your program works? Like, `sizeof(userInput) > 0` is silly, because that is always true, because `userInput` is a pointer and pointers are all the sam size (4 bytes or 8 bytes)

Comment: @user253751 that is something I did not know, from what I understood until now it would give me the size of the array I passed to it, thanks for that bit of new knowledge